# Infinite "bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local:/bin" in Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew

2 Updates:

I updated bash shell to Zsh with "chsh -s /bin/zsh" which seemed to do something.

I no longer get [Process Completed] or an infinite loop. Just a large block of text when typing /bin/ZSH -x (instead of bash). But maybe that's right, for the life of me can't find anywhere that explains what that command does.
When I quit and restart Terminal then the giant text output goes away.

**I'm concerned that I still have self-referencing loops somewhere on my drive and that I haven't truly solved the issue?**

Used "brew doctor" and updated a couple things. and looks like I'm good to go other than that.

Thank you to Allan and mmmmmmm for already providing some answers.

---

Old:
Hopefully you can already tell how new I am to command line.

I was almost finished installing homebrew when I kept getting an error that says

[Process completed]

So I am diagnosing that by going running a new window with the command

/bin/bash -x

However when I do that, I get an infinite loop:

[image: loopity loop]

My plan after the command above was to then do: sudo nano .bash_profile and then delete with CTRL X. However, I can't do that while my computer is running itself into the ground.

Any and all advice appreciated.

Comment: It is possible your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` (or similar) are sourcing each other. Can you press `Ctrl-C` to see if you can break the loop?

Comment: Or alternatively use TextEdit (or other GUI editor) to see what is in .bashrc and .bash_profile ( or if the latter does not exist .profile)

Comment: Thanks for the updates, but until we can see what's actually in those files, we can only guess.  Can you post the contents of the files mentioned in comments?

Comment: Also, why are you launching your shells in debug mode (the `-x` flag).  Is there an overarching issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: in .bash_profile, I had this;

'# Add Homebrew's executable directory to the front of the PATH.
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH 
source ~/.bash_profile 

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"'

_I removed the first export._

In .zshrc I had this:

'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
'


_I removed one of these as well._

Am I missing anything? And no overarching issue, just don't know what I'm doing. Thanks for the help @Allan

Comment: If it fixed your issue, post an answer to assist others that encounter this type of problem.

Comment: Well that's what I'm wondering, if deleting the extra 'export' lines solved the hidden self referencing loop.